# Redirect works in cmd but not from .bat or .cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn

I would like to redirect the output of `svn info` to a file.

If I execute `svn info --show-item=revision "url">output.txt` in cmd it work, but if I put it in a batch or cmd file it displays shortly the revision number in the appearing terminal but it doesnt gets redirected to the file.

I also tried `%~dp0` for the file location.

Even if I place `PAUSE` in the second line it wont pause. Executing with admin causes the terminal to ask for username and password but after I input correctly it fails.

How can i achive the redirect with a batch script? (I want to use the file to display the revision in a webapp)

Comment: How exactly did you try `%~dp0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect like that shown in your command, `>output.txt`, should work just fine in a batch file.

Copy and paste your command into a batch file and replace 'url' with an existing URL.

As mentioned by @Gerhard Barnard, make sure your batch file is not named "svn.bat".

Comment: As I tested the command line in cmd I just copied the line from the batch file to the terminal and it worked. Not sure what was wrong but after a view tries it worked. Maybe to enhance the answer for others who find this issue by google: What is the difference between .cmd or .bat? What role could quoation marks make in this setup?